# Do i delete the Bitcoin folder & data directory in Appdata after i copy it on an encrypted drive?

Tags: wallet, security, backup, encryption

I am trying to complete the instructions described here https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Securing_your_wallet#Windows . I have already done the Truecrypt part and installed the Bitcoin client. But i have one question i need help with before i can continue. Do i delete the Bitcoin folder & data directory in Appdata after i copy it onto an encrypted drive ? Or does it need to remain there to function even though it would then also be in the encrypted drive if not deleted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to delete **wallet.dat** - that's the only file with sensitive information. (You might want to run a utility such as [unix shred](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shred_%28Unix%29) on it to make sure it's really deleted).

**Just a warning** - before deleting, rename the file, and try to copy it from your backup and see if everything works.

Comment: Thank you ! I will try this today. I should do the last part you said to test it out before i point the Bitcoin client to start from the new directory correct ?

Comment: The test is simple - rename your wallet.dat, then copy it over from backup. The data directory itself is irrelevant all except the wallet.dat - if restoring that works, you're safe.